# is it possible to use a real machine virtualized?

Tags: windows, linux, virtualization, boot

I have a dual boot workstation where I mainly use my favorite flavor of Linux, but occasionally I need to log into its Windows XP installation. Is there any way to use this Windows partition virtualized into the linux host?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Although it may have some caveats. You don't mention the virtualization software you are using, but for virtual box i found a short [tutorial](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=769883) and a bit longer one [here](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=9697).

Comment: So far as I can tell, that is a one-off P2V conversion that creates a vmdk image separate from the installed Windows partition. Unless you have a separate partition for application data, running apps in the VM would not update data accessible by cold-booting Windows - would it?

Comment: @Ahe, regarding the virtualization software I still open to what will be better and/or easier. I know, for instance, VMware workstation is a more mature product, but VirtualBox is also not that far behind. I also thought of Xen, but I never used it.